# Does Android 2.2 log digits dialed during a call, and if so, how can I clear this log?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, security, call-history

Some voice jails that I call require me to enter a password. Are the digits I type while a call is active logged (as call dialing is), and if so, how can I remove them from the log? As you might guess, I want to keep any passwords out of persistent storage.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it's not logged by the default dialer.

Comment: Certainly the answer I am looking for! :) Do you have references or evidence you might point to; or, if this is based on your observations, maybe you could say a little more about how you observed this?